# SQL code to download a file from an FTP

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ftp

Does anyone have a way I can download a file from an FTP using SQL Server 2008 (don't want to use SSIS)?

Is there a better way to do this than using SQL?

Comment: "better way" - to do what? If you explain a bit more what you're trying to accomplish we'll have a better chance at offering some alternatives.

Comment: Well, starting an FTP server would be a good start.

Comment: Why does SQL Server have to do this?

Comment: Well, I'm basically trying to just log in once a morning to download a file from an ftp server.  Once I have the file, then I will run my stored procedures to bulk insert the data, etc.

I figured I'd do this in SQL server as it would be easiest to keep everything under one roof.

Comment: Why not SSIS? I know it's kind of "meh", but it is still "under one roof" of SQL Server.

Comment: If you are getting a file from an FTP server and loading it to SQL server, then SISS is the right tool. You could also do a batch script and scheduled task, but SISS is nice since it is integrated right with the Database.

Comment: I am having a really hard time figuring SSIS out.  I have read a few tutorials on FTP connections, but it seems like there is some .NET programming involved.  If anyone has a good resource, please forward it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have xp_cmdshell access you can use this http://www.nigelrivett.net/FTP/s_ftp_GetFile.html

Comment: That's the script I have been working with.  It keeps giving me invalid command errors on the first few exec commands.

Comment: It's likely you don't have access to xp_cmdshell.  Is this on a local SQL server or one on another server at a company?  Any DBA worth his weight in rice would prevent people from using xp_cmdshell as it gives you the ability to run command line utilities on the server itself.

Comment: I enabled xp_cmdshell.  This is a local SQL server to which no one else will have access.

Comment: Ok, I've set the script up locally as well, and unfortunately it turns out that FTP is blocked on the network here.  Which does make me wonder... do you have FTP blocked as well?  Simple question, but sometimes the basics get you.

Comment: yes, i think FTP is blocked too!  I got a script working on my home network perfectly, but on this network, I can't FTP, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

You can write stored procedure in .NET.

Working with FTP in C# (or VB.NET) is pretty easy. We had a project a couple of years ago where we needed exactly the same. So we have created several .NET stored procedures like:

`ftpGetList(serverAdress, username, password, remotePath)` - it returned us the list or remote files and folders as rowset

and next one was

`ftpGetFile(serverAdress, username, password, remotePath, localPath)` - it downloaded and saved the file locally.

Using C# has an advantage, because you can control credential, ftp mode and proxy settings.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps. The page pretty much walks you through the process of using the SSIS package for FTP'ing with sending and receiving files.

SSIS Script task that FTP's files

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/2b7cf6b5-d16d-44cd-954d-68e9ba98ee91/

Good luck