# How to get latest file name from folder?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have used below to get the list of files from folder. For the list I need to get only the latest file name.

Please suggest, where do I need to change the code to get the latest file name?

```
DROP TABLE #File
GO
--===== Create a holding table for the file names
 CREATE TABLE #File
        (
        FileName    SYSNAME,
        Depth       TINYINT,
        IsFile      TINYINT
        )
;
--===== Capture the names in the desired directory
     -- (Change "C:\Temp" to the directory of your choice)
 INSERT INTO #File
        (FileName, Depth, IsFile)
 EXEC xp_DirTree N'\\Backup-server\Include\Monthly\Sales\',1,1

;
--===== Find the latest file using the "constant" characters
     -- in the file name and the ISO style date.
 SELECT TOP 1 
        FileName
   FROM #File
  WHERE IsFile = 1
    AND FileName LIKE 'Sales_backup_*.bak' ESCAPE '_'
  ORDER BY FileName DESC

  select *from #file
```

Comment: I don't see any date/time columns in your file table.

Comment: The files are like this  Sales_backup_201201312300.rar
Sales_backup_201202292300.rar
Sales_backup_201203312300.rar  so I need the latest backup Sales_backup_201203312300.rar. like this I have 60 files in folder. every time I need is 60th file.

Comment: This is very good code...at least to get all file names in table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in this case, the file name contains what appears to be the creation date as a number.
`Sales_backup_201201312300.rar` probably means that the file was created on 2012-01-31 at 23:00.
So all you have to do is get the file with the largest number in it's name:

```
 SELECT TOP 1 FileName, Depth, IsFile
 FROM #File
 WHERE IsFile = 1
 ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(FileName, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', FileName), 12) As BigInt) DESC
```

Note: If any of your files does not contain numbers in it's name, this sql statement will raise an error. to overcome this you can do something like this:

```
 ;WITH CTE AS
 (
     SELECT FileName, Depth, IsFile
     FROM #File
     WHERE IsFile = 1
     AND PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', FileName) > 0
 )

 SELECT TOP 1 FileName, Depth, IsFile
 FROM CTE
 ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(FileName, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', FileName), 12) As BigInt) DESC
```

### Update:

Following your comment, you first need to unify the file names before you can compare them.
For that I came up with this solution:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  FileName,
            Depth, 
            REPLACE( 
            CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9][_][0-9]%', FileName) = 0 THEN
                    REPLACE(FileName, '.rar', '00_0000000.rar')
            ELSE 
                FileName
            END, '_', '')
            As UnifiedFormatFileName
    FROM #File
    WHERE IsFile = 1
    AND PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', FileName) > 0
)

SELECT TOP 1 FileName, Depth
FROM CTE
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(UnifiedFormatFileName, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', UnifiedFormatFileName), 21) As Numeric(21,0)) DESC
```

You can see it in action on [rextester.](http://rextester.com/SNGW81861)

Comment: Thanks. When I execute this getting message 60 rows affected but none is returning . column names showing blank.  some of the files are like this. Sales_backup_2015_08_31_203002_1718153.rar
Sales_backup_2015_09_30_203001_6301490.rar
Sales_backup_2015_10_31_203003_4130018.rar  would this making difference?

Comment: Yes, it would make a difference.

Comment: showing this message with blank column names when I execute query (60 row(s) affected)
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 20
Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

Comment: Then perhaps you should edit your question and supply some real sample data, since I've been testing on the file names from your comments and as you can see in the link, I got it to work with that data.

Comment: Thanks for your answers!. got it used this   select  top 1 *from #file 
  where Isfile =1 and FileName LIKE 'Sales_backup%' 
  order by FILENAME DESC

Comment: Can please suggest how to add the latest file name Sales_backup_2016_09_11_203002_1463153.rar into RESTORE COMMAND. I have tried with Restore syntax but not getting results.

Comment: Well, MSDN's example is `RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks2012  
   FROM DISK = 'Z:\SQLServerBackups\AdventureWorks2012.bak' ;`, Couldn't find any metion if the address must be hard coded or can be a variable. Also, I didn't find an option to restore from a rar file, only from a bak file.

Answer (score 0):

The .rar extension makes me think this is a zipped file.  If it is zipped you need to download it, (presumably from an FTP folder) using some kind of scripting language, and use the same script to unzip and save the file (either in the same folder or another folder).  You may want to see this.

http://www.itworld.com/article/2847292/how-to-fetch-a-file-from-ftp-and-import-into-sql-server-automatically.html

See this these links for some additional background.

[SQL code to download a file from an FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624600/sql-code-to-download-a-file-from-an-ftp)

https://www.virtualobjectives.com.au/sqlserver/ftp_scripts.htm

Post back if you have additional questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
--My Text File within This path D:\TXTFILE\
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ZipTable') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #ZipTable
    CREATE TABLE #ZipTable(MDATE VARCHAR(8000))
    INSERT #ZipTable
    EXEC MASTER.DBO.XP_CMDSHELL 'DIR D:\TXTFILE\' 


DECLARE @SYS_USR AS NVARCHAR(1000),@PC_NAME AS NVARCHAR(100)
    SET @SYS_USR = SYSTEM_USER
    SELECT @PC_NAME=SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@SYS_USR,PATINDEX('%\%',@SYS_USR),100),2,LEN(SUBSTRING(@SYS_USR,PATINDEX('%\%',@SYS_USR),100)))
    print @PC_NAME
    print @SYS_USR

        Truncate table FinalZip
    Insert into FinalZip
    SELECT @PC_NAME as USERNAME,SUBSTRING(MDATE,PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%',MDATE),100)  FNAME ,SUBSTRING(MDATE,1,18) AS 'MODIFIEDDATE' 
    FROM #ZipTable WHERE MDATE LIKE '%.txt%'

    select * from FinalZip where modifieddate in (select max(modifieddate) from FinalZip)
```